# How to find all apps using GPS?

Tags: android, android-location

Is there a way to programatically enumerate all apps that are currently using GPS? This would probably be equivalent to listing all LocationListeners registered with LocationManager. I have so far tried to get an instance of LocationManager, and then read contents of private mListeners hashmap, but it does not seem to contain any LocationListeners other apps use.

Comment: "I have so far tried to get an instance of LocationManager, and then read contents of private mListeners hashmap, but it does not seem to contain any LocationListeners other apps use" -- those listeners are in other processes, not yours.

Comment: @CommonsWare thats what I thought. Unfortunately doesnt get me anywhere...